# How to edit datesec array in edgar_v5_2015 emission files (netcdf format) using NCO?

Tags: nco

I am using EDGAR V5 2015 emission files (edgar_v5_2015__0.1x0.1.nc) for WRF-Chem simulation. After giving the `ncdump -v date,datesec edgar_v5_2015_CO_0.1x0.1.nc > ncdump.log` command, I learned that the date and datesec variables of the emission file are- data:

```
date = 20150101, 20150201, 20150301, 20150401, 20150501, 20150601, 20150701, 20150801, 20150901, 20151001, 20151101, 20151201 ;

datesec = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ; }
```

I want to change the last date in the 'date' array from '20151201' to '20151231'. How to do that using NCO? I have gone through the user guide. But, I am having difficulties understanding what command line I should use for this since I have never used NCO before.

Comment: I guess the option is to use ncap2 (please look at the examples in https://sourceforge.net/p/nco/discussion/9829/thread/dd953366/). It looks like the command might be something like `ncap2 -s 'date(:)={20150101,20150201,...,20151231}' filex.nc x.nc ` . You have to specify all the new values for `date`.

Comment: Hi @msi_gerva, I took your suggestion and gave the following command: ncap2 -s **'date(:)={20150101, 20150201, 20150301, 20150401, 20150501, 20150601, 20150701, 20150801, 20150901, 20151001, 20151101, 20151231}' edgar_v5_2015_CO_0.1x0.1.nc EDGARV5_2015_CO_0.1x0.1.nc**. But, I am getting the following error: ** ncap2: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libnco-4.7.5.so: undefined symbol: nc_inq_format_extended**. Can you tell me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

@msi_gerva is correct. The symbol lookup error appears to be a bug. It will probably disappear if you switch to using an updated NCO (4.7.5 is years old), or rebuild your version 4.7.5 to link to a recent version of netCDF.

Comment: Thank you @Charlie Sir. I have installed the recent version of NCO, and it worked. Thank you again.